# Getting the relativistic inner product of Siegel's book

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, klein-gordon-equation

Last time I was discussing with a physicist about quantum field theory and how in the firsts chapters of textbooks it is often regarded that the Klein-Gordon equation does not have a positive definite inner product/probability density. He told me that he had seen a book that obtains a positive probability density. The author just change the sign with a factor $\epsilon(p^0)$ but I cannot understand what he is doing.
The book is Fields by Warren Siegel
https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9912205

On page 323 he says

[image]

> where the $\epsilon(p^0)$ appears because the contour integral gives a + at later times (positive energy) and a − at earlier times (negative energy).

Could someone help out with an explanation of why there is a contour integral producing a $\epsilon(p^0)$ factor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"contour" should have been "boundary".
(Explanation of time vs. energy in previous subsection.)
Just fixed in v4:

http://insti.physics.sunysb.edu/~siegel/errata.shtml

Comment: Always nice to have the true expert answer!